# Import an LSDYAN deck in ANSA with script

Tags: python

I want to do a script in ANSA for importing a LS DYNA deck. I am only getting the output message "Code generation completed" but it doesn't import anything. Here is the line I am using:

## PYTHON script

```
import os
import ansa
from ansa import base
from ansa import constants
from ansa import utils

def main():

     deck=constants.LSDYNA

     base.InputLSDyna(filename="C:/Documents/Model_test.k", nodes_id="offset", elements_id="offset", properties_id="offset", materials_id="offset", sets_id="offset", model_action="new_model_in_active_window", version="971r10")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Can anybody help please?
Thank you